# Tabeling two lists of equal length

Tags: r

I am trying to sort of Punnett square or crosstable two lists of letters of equal length, without sorting or removing duplicates.

```
   al = "ABADCX"
   bl = "ABADCY"

   al = strsplit(al, "")
   bl = strsplit(bl, "")

   table(al[[1]], bl[[1]])
```

I would like to have a return where the table simply gives a 1 when the row and column match and a 0 when they don't. Then later I would like to extract the letter by letter sequence of 1's and 0's into a list.

Is this possible without a time consuming for loop?

Comment: For me it is not clear what you exactly want to have as output. Do you want to match all the letters of al with bl and check whether they are the same yes or no? So then the output will be a vector with true if they match and false if they do not match.

Comment: It is not clear what you need. Anything close to `Map('==', al, bl)`?

Comment: Maybe `+(length(intersect(al[[1]], bl[[1]])) > 0)` ?